# When a module is uninstalled on a virtual environment, does it remain uninstalled outside the virtualenv?

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, python-venv

I have numpy 1.16 installed due to it being listed as the specific version that ought to be used for a program to function properly. After installing numpy 1.19 in a virtual environment, I noticed the following messages:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy
Attempting uninstall: numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.16.6
Uninstalling numpy-1.16.6:
Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.16.6
```

Will numpy 1.16 remain when I deactivate the virtual environment or will I have to reinstall it with pip once I finish using version 1.19?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed numpy 1.16 for a specific virtual environment and replaced it with 1.9 it will not be there in the virtual environment but you will not need pip install for future use in other projects.

Which means it will not be uninstalled outside of the virtualenv.